# for GKE how can we control the configuration of the control plane?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kube-apiserver

I am creating a GKE cluster (4 nodes) and deploying applications on it.

While doing that the API server become unresponsive for a few minutes.

Want to create a GKE cluster with scaled control plane.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? GKE master is managed by google only and you cannot do anything with that, you cannot change master configuration. For what purpose you need scaled control plane? Do you need to use HPA or Cluster Autoscaler?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment section, you cannot change anything in the GKE master, its fully managed by googler.

In overall [GKE Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine#section-9) you can find information that it's managed by GKE SRE

> **Fully managed:** GKE clusters are fully managed by Google Site Reliability Engineers (SREs), ensuring your cluster is available and up-to-date.

One of the reasons why only Google can manage your cluster is described [Vulnerability and patch management](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/control-plane-security#vulnerability_and_patch_management) part of GKE documentation, however there are a few more reasons.

> GKE control plane components are managed by a team of Google site reliability engineers, and are kept up to date with the latest security patches. This includes patches to the host operating system, Kubernetes components, and containers running on the control plane VMs.

Additional information you can find also in [Control plane security](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/control-plane-security):

> Under the Shared Responsibility Model, Google manages the GKE control plane components for you. The control plane includes the Kubernetes API server, etcd, and other controllers. Google is responsible for securing the control plane, though you might be able to configure certain options based on your requirements. You are responsible for securing your nodes, containers, and Pods.

Regarding the second part, where you want to have multiple masters, you can achieve it creating [Regional Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters).

> In contrast to [zonal clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters#zonal_clusters) that have a single control plane in a single [zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available), regional clusters increase the availability of both a cluster's control plane and its nodes by replicating them across multiple zones in a [region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/regions-zones#available). This provides the advantages of [multi-zonal clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters#multi-zonal_clusters)
>
> ...
>
> The control plane is replicated across three zones of a region. For node pools, you can manually specify the zone(s) in which the cluster's node pools run or you can use the default configuration, which replicates each node pool across three zones of the control plane's region. All zones must be within the same region as the cluster's control plane.

**To sum up:**

- Google is responsible for your GKE cluster control plane, and you can't do much about it
- If you want to have more Control Plane, you can achieve this by using `Regional` cluster instead of `Zonal`
- Just as addition, if your application have issues with accessibility, you can think about [HPA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/horizontalpodautoscaler) or [Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler)

Comment: While installing various applications on GKE (Automated package installations), the API server is not accessible multiple time leaving a bad experience for users. Same packages when installed on other clouds(EKS, AKS) go through without a hitch.  Wondering how can we tweak control plane to be available. Will try with regional cluster and check. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, regional clusters should solve this. With zonal clusters you can see master go away for a short time while it upgrades, resizes (based on your node sizes) or gets repaired.
So if you need a HA control plane, go regional.